# Netbeans Editor: How to add an additional script type to behave like text/html?

Tags: javascript, netbeans, configuration, editor, jsrender

Here's my problem: 
I'm using NetBeans to edit a Smarty template file, and inside this file is a portion that I'm using as a jsRender template. Its declaration is: `<script type="text/x-jsrender">` which makes it "invisible" to the end user.

Problem is, this also turns off (inside that script block) all the things that I like about NetBeans, namely the auto-formatting, color highlighting, etc., because it does not know what to do with x-jsrender content.

If I (temporarily) use `<script type="text/html">` coloring etc. works again, but to switch permanently back and forth to get the editor to play "nice" is a major inconvenience.

What I'd like Netbeans to do: I want to configure it to recognize the custom script type of "text/x-jsrender" to be the same as "text/html", and to apply the same rules.

Any help/pointers appreciated.

(Edited: wrong type in post title)

Comment: If you cannot get Netbeans to recognize text/x-jsrender, you can just use text/html, which will work fine for JsRender. (JsRender does not actually require it to be text/x-jsrender).

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick! Just one thing to keep in mind: at least with NetBeans 8.1, any script tag that follows behind the text/html will not be auto-formatted (so there's still something that Netbeans considers "not quite right").